# How to encapsualte code blocks into a frame when exporting to pdf?

Tags: pdf, emacs, org-mode

I have been using org-mode + emacs for a while now, and I love how easy it is to produce contents. I often use the html + pdf export combo from the same document (first, a web page, following, a pdf document). My problem is about exporting code blocks (`#+BEGIN_SRC`...) to pdf.

To **html**, the export command (`C-c C-e h h`) gives me a satisfactory solution: it uses a frame to encapsulate the code (showing the programming language when you rest the mouse pointer on it) and uses a different frame for the resulting messages (as I set `:export both`). When using `#+CAPTION: my caption here` before the `#+BEGIN_SRC`, resulting html page includes "*Listing #: my caption here*" before the code frame.

To **pdf**, the document generated by export command (`C-c C-e l p`) doesn't have frames around neither code or results (a real mess), and captions show up as "*Figure #: my caption here*" in between the code and results.

How do I get both **different frames for code and results**  and **Listings-like captions** for my code blocks when exporting from org-mode to pdf?

Here is a minimal example:

```
#+TITLE: EXPORT TESTINGS
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

#+CAPTION: Caption, my caption!
#+BEGIN_SRC C :results output :exports both
int i, x = 10;
for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    printf("%d ",i);
printf(" ~ %d\n", x);
#+END_SRC
```

Here is the resulting [html](http://iperetta.dx.am/test/test.html) and the resulting [pdf](http://iperetta.dx.am/test/test.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Based on the Alex Ott answer (and a couple hours of web browsing) I finally did it.*

**We are going to use the `minted` package**. For completness, this how I had to set up everything:

---

### Python is needed

`minted` use a Python package to highlight syntax called [Pygmets](https://pygments.org). You could install it with:

```
pip install Pygments
```

---

### Emacs setup

- In org file preamble you need the line: `#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{minted}`
- Source code block export use the variable `org-latex-listings`. You have to set it with: `(setq org-latex-listings 'minted)`.
- Last but not least, you have to allow `pdflatex` to execute  shell commands in order to use the Python package `Pygments`. The option is `-shell-escape`. And the emacs variable that describes the call to the LaTeX compiler is `org-latex-pdf-process`.

To achieve those 3 points, I have added this snipet in my init file

```
;; inside .emacs file
(setq org-latex-listings 'minted
      org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
      org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

NB: see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121383/how-does-the-latex-compile-chain-work-exactly) to understand why three calls to pdflatex are needed. If you use bibtex you have to insert the appropriate line.

---

### Back to your Org file

Now you can add the LaTeX attribute on top of your source code block:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (defun Fib (n)
    (if (< n 2) n (+ (Fib (- n 1)) (Fib (- n 2)))))
#+END_SRC
```

*Et voilà !*
[image]

---

### Minted manual

To use different frame styles go and check the [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf)

Comment: I tried this but the output is completely ignored, is that intentional? Ideally I'd want the output of the code block (when `:exports both`) in a minted environment `txt`.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav Did you execute the code block into your org file? Can you see the output inside the org file?

Comment: Yes, the output is there. And ordinarily it's have been output in latex as verbatim I think.

Comment: The export of results is another topic. Have you looked here : https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html ?

Comment: Adding `:wrap src text` in header Works, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Org-mode uses Minted package for source code highlighting in PDF/LaTeX

You can pass options to Minted package if you use following configuration parameter to specific code block:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single
```

Or if you want to make these changes for all files, then you need to customize ‘org-latex-listings-options’ and/or ‘org-latex-minted-options’ variables.

See the documentation for Minted LaTeX package, and maybe these 2 answers on TeX stackexchange: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342683/specify-box-with-header-around-listing%201), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112559/box-around-minted-environment)

Comment: I see your answer is accepted but I cannot make it work. Where do you add this line? At the beginning of the file?

Comment: yes, at beginning of file (at least if I remember correctly :-)